# Is there a way to even out the paint without painting whole wall

Tags: painting

Just painted second coat and noticed botches that weren't there after the first coat.

What's the best way to smooth it out without painting the whole wall?

[image: Wall with noticeable Botches]
[image: Same wall from different angle]

Comment: You sure that is from your paint job?  Looks like a drywall screw hole covered but not sanded well.

Comment: To which picture are you referring? At the time, we had just waited ~2 hours for the second coat of paint to dry. I noticed any additional paint applied will leave botches where the roller stopped and started (as it seemed that way in the pictures above.

Answer (score 1):

Sand it a bit and paint over it. Feather out the edges. Should work just fine.

Comment: I don't feel any roughness at the spots, so I am a bit cautious of doing that. Also, could you elaborate on "Feather out the edges"? Thanks

Comment: @Aggieborn feathering the edges means to spread the paint out from the area painting. So you'd have your wet paint in the center and then you'd spread that via brush our roller out in all directions. DMoore has a good point, though...if the issue is that it's a badly sanded drywall mud  joint, you may have to sand down to that first.